# How can you run an HttpListener and TcpListener on different IP addresses with the same port?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to listen for HTTP requests and TCP connections on the same port but on different IP addresses.

```
string prefix = "http://192.168.1.2:40000/";
HttpListener http = new HttpListener();
http.Prefixes.Add(prefix);

IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.3"), 40000);
TcpListener tcp = new TcpListener(ep);
```

If I start the HttpListener first, I get an error when starting the TcpListener.

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

If I start the TcpListener first, I get an error when starting the HttpListener.

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

When the HttpListener is running, netstat reveals that it's only listening on the IP address specified, but it's running in the System process (PID 4).

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
TCP    192.168.1.2:40000      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

When the TcpListener is running, it's also only listening on the IP address specified, but it's running in my application's process.

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
TCP    192.168.1.3:40000      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       18316
```

Even though they listen on different IP addresses, there's still a conflict that won't let me do both at the same time.

I am able to run two HttpListeners and two TcpListeners on different IP addresses with the same port, however.

---

**Update**

The question was asked:

> How do you have assigned two local IP addresses on the same LAN segment?

Originally I had two IP addresses on the same network adapter in the same subnet (255.255.0.0). (See how this is possible at https://superuser.com/questions/571575/connect-to-two-lan-networks-with-a-single-card).

To rule out this as an issue, I setup a virtual machine with two network adapters on different subnets. The results were the same.

Comment: @Eser Do you have any documentation that it's not just a configuration issue?

Comment: Its roots are [Berkeley sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) and don't see any reason to change the inner workings...

Comment: How do you have assigned two local IP addresses on the same LAN segment? Sounds like you need to provide more detail as to the source machine config. If those two addresses are on different segments, this seems like it should work.

Comment: @JamieMeyer Please see the update in my question.

Comment: In the first case, the answer *seems* obvious that a single IP stack was in use, and thus @Eser's response is spot on. In the VM configuration, it still should work. I would do basic networking tests with ping and tracert to see if that sheds any light on the situation.

Comment: @JamieMeyer I don't see how Eser was spot on. It is demonstrably possible to run two sockets using the same port on different IP addresses regardless of whether they are on the same segment. He also stated that it was not possible, and yet it was just a configuration issue.

Comment: The original post neglected to mention that this was running on IIS. You should edit the post to indicate that, so that others will benefit from what you learned. I will file this away as well. ;-)

Comment: @JamieMeyer It's not running on IIS. It's a C# application using HttpListener. Both IIS and HttpListener use HTTP.sys as their underlying technology. But tagging it with IIS may benefit others. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you must tell HTTP.sys which IP addresses to listen on because it hijacks them all by default.

In my case, running the following command allowed me to run HttpListener and TcpListener on the same port on different IP addresses.

```
netsh http add iplisten 192.168.1.2
```

Sources

- [Disabling HTTPS Socket Pooling](http://forums.iis.net/t/1161882.aspx?Disabling%20HTTPS%20Socket%20Pooling)
- [add iplisten](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc307219(VS.85).aspx)